# WordPress get post id passed in permalink?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, get

How do  I get the post id which is passed in permalink. In wordpress, I have seen this:

```
href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"
```

Using `JQuery` get method I am able to pass `href` attribute to process in php. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('Selector').on('click', function(){
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                $.get('url',
                {
                    'post_id' : href    
                }, 
                function(data){
                        alert(data);    
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It gives me post permalink as desired, but How do I get `$post->ID` instead. I have used `url_to_postid` method after getting the permalink but that's not working, so I want to get `$post->ID` if that's possible. Thank you for your help

Comment: _I have used `url_to_postid` method after getting the permalink but that's not working:_ are you getting an error message with that?

Comment: I'm getting 0, `WordPress` codex has mentioned the same, you'll get 0 on failure

Comment: `get_permalink` is within the loop?

Comment: I can't see any `id` attribute (while you are using in jquery) Please post your full code.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question now, I got the answer anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach post ID to the link in data attribute:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"
   data-id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($post->ID); ?>"
>...</a>
```

And then retrieve it in jQuery:

```
var postID = $(this).data('id');
```